# Adding items into an Array in BASH

Tags: arrays, bash, select

I am looking for a way to add items from a particular column in a file into an array using BASH.
Columns are tab separated
eg:

A file (test.txt) with values:

1. This is my name   3
2. Name   ryu
3. List item
4. List item
   2b.   etc   etc

I am using:

`element=$(cat test.txt | awk -F'\t' '{print $2}' | sort -u)`

`arr=()`

`arr=+( "$element" )`

Which seems to work up to the point of adding in to the array. When I echo the array it has taken 'This is my name' as four separate elements. Therefore when I use the select statement it does not recognize the elements in their entirety. i.e it returns a list such as:
 1. This
 2. is
 3. my
 4. name
 5. Name

The only way I can think of is to use sed before adding to the array to substitute the space with an underscore for example and then remove it at a later stage. However if a file genuinely included an underscore this would affect it.

I would like my select statement to return a list such as:

1. This is my name
2. Name

When I cat the array all the elements are there. However, when I use the select command to create a menu with those elements the elements with white apace are read as separate elements.
 cat my array gives
 This is my name Name 
select x in array gives me 
 1. This 
 2. is 
 3. my 
 4. name 
 5. Name

I need the select command to give me

1.This is my name

2.Name

Comment: `arr+=( "$element" )` definitely only adds one element, not four.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/5s1vyJ demonstrating that. Could you show us a full, standalone reproducer *including* the select statement itself?

Answer (score 1):

There is a special buildin readarray(mapfile) for that

```
readarray -t arr <test.txt
$ for item in "${arr[@]}"; { echo $item; }
1. This is my name 3
2. Name ryu
3. List item
4. List item 2b. etc etc
```

Comment: Do you really want the `\n`s to be there in the elements? (the `-t` argument to `readarray` is needed to suppress them).

Comment: ```When I cat the array all the elements are there. 
However, when I use the select command to create a menu with those elements the elements with white apace are read as separate elements. 

cat my array gives

This is my name
Name

select x in array gives me

1. This 
2. is
3. my
4. name
5. Name

I need the select command to give me

1. This is my name
2. Name
```